# Special characters missing in target while copying data with azure data factory from sql server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, delta-lake

In sql server, we have special characters in data like ~$534 but after copying to delta lake with ADF some special characters are missing in the target

Comment: Can you please share an example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

First try to copy the ***SQL table to Azure Blob Storage as csv file*** in ADF and check if any special characters are missing in that CSV file.

If data in CSV is correct, then you can copy that csv file to delta lake as table with ADF. If it results same as before, you can reach out to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/)  or can raise a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/features/issues).